# How to position element next to another without modifying styling to the first element?

Tags: html, css, positioning

CSS is still fairly new to me. I have a `div` element and want to define a `button` element that would be placed right of the `div` element. However, I want to do this without modifying any of the styling of the `div` element. Is this possible? Edit: If yes, please show me an example :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Dan_1993/5ffbv/ I hope this answers your question.

Comment: *Example:* `<div></div> <input type="button" />`.  On a more serious note, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @user2406160, this fails my condition that the styling of the parent (note that I'd prefer the button to be the next element, not a child element) must not be modified. In your case, you added `position:relative;` to the parent `div`, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @BLaZuRE, I want to have a JS script that adds buttons to all divs on a page without messing with any of the original site HTML and CSS. Does that make sense? :)

Comment: @mart1n why are you trying to avoid it? http://jsfiddle.net/Dan_1993/TR2hr/2/ better...?

Comment: @user2406160 I didn't know that was a button until I read the text.  Thanks for clarifying that :) .

Comment: Really? oh you're very much welcome, I did it just for your peace of mind, I hope you can sleep tonight now.

Comment: @user2406160, because I want it to be universal for any page without affecting the styling of that page, meaning that the `div` element is static and the dynamically added `button` element should add w/e styling is necessary to make it to the right of the `div` element. To make it simple, I'm looking for rules in the "button" section here: http://jsfiddle.net/gUHsp/ .

Comment: @user2406160 Actualy, I'm sleep-deprived, that's why I'm making stupid jokes.  Thanks, though.  Anyway, I suggest to you and future users to put your answer in text instead of a fiddle website, so years down the road someone doesn't encounter a broken link to a potentially helpful solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position:absolute` for that element and align it using `right`/`left` and `top`/`bottom` css rules, this will align the element relative to the entire webpage (or nearest `position:relative` parent), but what you're looking for is usually done by making both elements `float:right/left` or `display:inline-block`. *Note that the '/' in my answer indicate your choices, not actual css directives.*

Comment: Note: if you will be aligning an element with `float: right;`, it is a common workaround in certain situations to actually put that element before any elements in the same row/line in order to prevent a line break in certain browsers.

Comment: @BLaZuRE Floats are an interesting topic in and of themselves. Especially of note is the clearfix trick (<div style="float:none; clear:both;"></div>).

Comment: Half the stuff wouldn't be interesting if browsers would follow W3C standards and were strict about it.

Comment: Is there a way to define the absolute positioning to be centered in the middle of the preceding element? For completeness, I'm looking for a set of rules for the `button` here: http://jsfiddle.net/gUHsp/

Comment: No, there isn't. You cannot base rules on values of sibling elements. For completeness, we need more info on the overall layout of the page, as there are multiple solutions and most work best only in specific scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Simple add the

```
float:left
```

or

```
float:right
```

to style it will work fine and display after one and other.

Comment: Again, this fails my condition that the preceding `div`'s CSS cannot be modified. Please read question comments for more info.